# how to disable displaying of filename in the command bar when opening files in vim/nvim?

Tags: vimrc

Everytime I open a file vim displays the filename in the command bar, for example I run this:

```
vim test.test
```

vim will start with a statusline like this:

```
"test.test" [New File]                                            0,0-1        All
```

I'm already using an statusline that displays file name so how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:set shortmess+=F` to prevent Vim from echoing the current filename into the commandline.

See the documentation, e.g. [`:help 'shortmess'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shortmess%27)

Note, this might need a recent Vim, since the 'F' flag was always correctly respected. Some recent patches changed that, e.g. [8.1.310](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0310) or [8.1.110](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0110)

Comment: I got this issue in some recent versions, but limited for few type of files like `.csv`. Nevertheless this fix seams to be working.